# Change the diameter of a curved cylinder/pipe?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, transforms

I have a pipe/string shape which has irregular bends at a variety of angles. I would like to scale its diameter but keep the overall length the same. Is there a way to do this without starting again from scratch? I would like to keep the shape of the curve intact.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> with all faces selected, don't forget to check *Offset Even*.

[image]